# Design large web form for entry mode

Tags: web-app, forms

At my company I am developing and designing a web app(one man effort :( ) for entering data for a directory , basically the directory structure is as follows :

```
Categories 
  -> Offices (>=1)
    ->SubOffies(>=1)
       ->Addresses
       ->Phones
       ->Boards
       ->etc
```

So current implementation has different screens for the user to enter the data , but I think hard for the user to keep track of the data entry with different screens and I decided to put all the screens  in one big form but now I am confused.

**What is the best way to do something like that?**

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly will go in each of these forms ,I am not very sure about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a JS accordion form?

One such example here: http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/yui-accordion/form/